# Understanding a JavaScript For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

If I have variables and a for loop with a condition set-up like this:

```
var scores = [23, 53, 85];
var arrayLength = scores.length;
var i;

for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
```

Does the `i` refer to the scores array indexed position of 0, or is `i` just the counter number, which is set to 0?

I'm kinda confused on understanding what's happening.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `i` is just a number variable which is increment on each iteration up to the maximum index of the array.

Comment: As Pranav said it's just a number variable but you can use it to reference the indexes of the array like `scores[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see it in action:

```js
var scores = [23, 53, 85];
var arrayLength = scores.length;
var i;

for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log('i = ' + i + ', scores[i] = ' + scores[i]);
}
console.log('End of for loop: i = ' + i);
```

One important thing to understand is that `i` will be incremented until the condition `i < arrayLength` is not met anymore. So it ***will*** reach the value `3` but the for loop will end immediately. Therefore, the code inside the loop is not executed for `i = 3`.

Comment: OK, so if my var inside the for loop was set to `i = 1`, and then I ran `scores[i];`, the first iteration would output 53?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and showing me the snippet in action. Wish everybody would do that; it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`i` is just a counter number which is initially set to 0 and increments up to `arrayLength` (3 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

`i` just refers to a number that (in this case) counts up from 0 until `arrayLength`. You have to explicitly access the values in the array at each `i` by using `scores[i]`, after which you can modify/use the value in any way you see fit.

Comment: This was a clear explanation for me to understand what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

i is the counter number.

A for loop works like so:

For each value of array length, use i as a counter variable

each time through the loop increment the variable of i when you are done (i++)

you could expand it like so...

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
  console.log('position ' + i + ' is ' + scores[i]);
}//now that I am done, increment i and go through again until i is no longer less than array length
```

Answer (score 0):

Right so you have the set the i as a variable by initially going

var i;

Within the for statement you have set the i variable to 0.

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
}
```

Then the for statement is saying if i is less than the array length run the for statement. Each time the for statement runs you are adding 1 to i because of i++;

Every time the for statement will check to see if i is less than the arrayLength if it isnt it will exit out of the for.

So for this instance the for each would run 3 times because the array length is 3.

Make sure you have open and closing brackets on the for statement

So your for statement should look like this.
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    }